# Export Firewall Rules using PowerShell that include Program Path

Tags: powershell, windows-8.1

I'm looking for a way to export existing Windows Firewall rules using PowerShell **that includes the path of the Program being referenced** (for those rules which reference a program path instead of a port range).

`Get-NetFirewallRule` includes a lot of information but seems to be missing Program. Preferably in a human-readable format I can also automate with. Output as PowerShell objects would be best, but something tabular would be good enough.

What I've tried:

- Get-NetFirewallRule, piping to Get-Member, piping to Format-List *
- taking a Get-NetFirewallRule and serializing it with Export-CliXml with a high depth - the program path is not in the XML file.
- brief (brief!) poking around netsh
- I can manually do an export from WF.msc to get a tab delimited list, but I'd like something I can automate.
- I did find [this](http://gaurangpatel.net/exportimport-windows-firewall-setting-using-powershell), but it's not human readable and looks like an all/nothing import-export, not something I could use to extract only new rules

This is in the context of managing dozens of build VMs used for continuous integration at a software company, but could also apply to system administration of our other workstations.

So far, I have not found a solution that will let me take rules on one system (specific rules) and create a PowerShell script (or GPO or whatever) to add the same rule to other machines. All I'm missing is program path. Once I have that I can easily handle the rule creation aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Get-NetFirewallRule actually returns special objects.  Some of the object's properties can only be accessed with associated Get-NetFirewall* commands.

For application information, pipe the object into Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554860%28v=wps.630%29.aspx

```
PS C:\Users\Neil> get-netfirewallrule '{1A26910B-1B3B-4091-81E2-E3C7CBF02F45}' | get-netfirewallapplicationfilter


Program : C:\Program Files\MyProgram\thisProgram.exe
Package :
```

Comment: That is it! Thank you!! *internet high five*, and for other things it's Get-NetFirewallPortFilter, etc etc. Now I get it.